# Azure Databricks notebook not deployed via YAML deploynotebooks@0 task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-databricks

This is my YAML.

The notebooks are not deployed. the pipeline ran successfully but the notebooks are not deployed. What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Can you see any warnings or abnormal log information in the build pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Your `notebooksFolderPath` seems to be incorrect
either use `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` or `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` variables to get the notebooks

```yaml
- task: deploynotebooks@0
  displayName: 'Deploy Databricks notebooks'
  inputs:
    notebooksFolderPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/<path-to-notebooks-in-repository>'
    workspaceFolder: '/Shared'
```

or

```yaml
- task: deploynotebooks@0
  displayName: 'Deploy Databricks notebooks'
  inputs:
    notebooksFolderPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/<path-to-notebooks-in-repository>'
    workspaceFolder: '/Shared'
```

Here's the build agent typical pathes:

```sh
$(Build.SourcesDirectory) = /home/vsts/work/1/s
$(Build.BinariesDirectory) = /home/vsts/work/1/b
$(Pipeline.Workspace) = /home/vsts/work/1
```